# Merge/conact Panda Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I work with a panda Dataframe and I try to create a new table that combine two dataframe based in one column id using concate : My first Dataframe df1 :

[image]

My second Dataframe df2:
[image]

The desired result :
[image]

When I tried to use this code :

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id')
```

The result dataframe not show me the rows with id=3,4 and 6?
Anyone can help please ? Thank you

Comment: `result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id', how='left')`

Comment: Thank you @jesrael, this is what I look for it. And if I want o replace the "NA" with 0 which option chose ?

Comment: then use `result = result.fillna(0)`